# Llamar formulario y enviarle informacion al mismo Javascript Cordova

Tags: javascript, html, apache-cordova

2 consultas:
1- como puedo hacer para llamar un div(formulario) que tengo en mi html con javascript, es decir en mi caso mi aplicacion me muestra el div con id="pagina1" que es donde estan las tablas, pero quiero que al hacer click en una tabla me muestre lo que hay en el div con id="pagina2"

2-como puedo hacer para enviarle la informacion que hay en la tabla seleccionada desde el div id="pagina1" al div id="pagina2"

esto es lo que tengo en mi html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pagina1">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>LISTADO DE REMITOS PENDIENTES </h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="idResultado"></div>
        </div>

        
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="pagina2">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Registro de Remito </h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="titlepage">Ingrese los datos </div>
            <div class="ui-field-contain">

                <input type="text" id="txtCodRemito" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="Codigo Remito" required />
                <input type="datetime-local" id="txtfecha" name="birthdaytime">
                <select id="cbProveedor">
                    <option value="-1">Seleccione un Proveedor</option>
                </select>

                <select id="cbCombustible">
                    <option value="A">Seleccione un Combustible</option>
                    <option value="B">Debe Seleccionar un proveedor para cargar los combustibles</option>
                </select>

                <input type="text" id="txtLitros" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="Litros Cargados" required />
                <input type="text" id="txtMonto" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="Monto Total" required />
                <button id="btnCamara">Foto de Remito</button>
                <div style="border: 1px solid; width: 200px; min-height:100px; margin: 0 auto;">
                    <img src="" id="myImage" />
                </div>
                <button id="btnRegistrar">Registrar</button>
            </div>
            <div id="idResultado"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

para llamar a un formulario he intentando con

```
$("#página1").submit(function () {
        $('#pagina2').show();
        return false;
    });
```

y tambien con:

```
const rows = document.querySelectorAll("table[data-href]");
rows.forEach(row => {
       row.addEventListener("click", () => {
           window.location.href = row.dataset.href;
        });
});
```

este ultimo teniendo en cuenta que agregue a la etiqueta de cada tabla data-href='pagina2'

Comment: Y qué es lo que has intentado?

Comment: ahi agregue el codigo con el que he intentado cambiar de formulario